# Pyspark access the values after collect_list()

Tags: python, pyspark

I have what I feel is a silly issue while using collect_list() with pyspark. I searched StackOverflow but I couldn't find the answer to my problem.

After a normal aggregation I have the following dataset:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()
data = [{'users': '1', 'songs': 23},
        {'users': '1', 'songs': 28},
        {'users': '2', 'songs': 43},
        {'users': '2', 'songs': 63},
        {'users': '3', 'songs': 78},
        {'users': '3', 'songs': 33}]
  
# creating a dataframe
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data)

songs_mean = dataframe.groupBy('users').agg({'songs':'mean'}).agg(collect_list('avg(songs)')).collect()
songs_mean

#Output
[Row(collect_list(avg(songs))=[55.5, 25.5, 53.0])]
```

How can I access the nested list with the values? All I want is:

```
[55.5, 25.5, 53.0]
```

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the list by the **`index [0][0]`**

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
data = [{'users': '1', 'songs': 23},
        {'users': '1', 'songs': 28},
        {'users': '2', 'songs': 43},
        {'users': '2', 'songs': 63},
        {'users': '3', 'songs': 78},
        {'users': '3', 'songs': 33}]
  
# creating a dataframe
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data)

songs_mean = dataframe.groupBy('users').agg({'songs':'mean'}).agg(collect_list('avg(songs)')).collect()
print(songs_mean[0][0])
#[25.5, 55.5, 53.0]
```